# Magento advanced newsletter hide fields when logged

Tags: magento, newsletter

i`m using the Advanced Newsletter extension on my magento store: http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/advanced-newsletter.html

My problem is:

If the user is not logged he can see all input field (name, email...), but if he is logged all inputs disappears and he can only see the subscription button which only subscribe his account e-mail.

I need guest users and logged users seeing the same form! Both need to be able to choose any email they want to subscribe.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you post the code for the newsletter signup template?

Comment: @Osmar hi osmar, i have also find this problem if you solved it then please provide me answer for this problem to me.

Comment: This is an extension for Magento. Did you try to contact the developers for support?